# will gcloud show image-family options?

Tags: linux, cloud, google-compute-engine, vps, gcloud

How do I get a list of `image-family` options?

```
--image-family IMAGE_FAMILY
    The family of the image that the boot disk will be initialized with. When a family is specified instead of an image, the latest non-deprecated image associated with that family is used.

    By default, debian-8 is assumed for this flag.
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ gcloud compute images list
NAME                                 PROJECT          FAMILY           DEPRECATED  STATUS
centos-6-v20160718                   centos-cloud     centos-6                     READY
centos-7-v20160718                   centos-cloud     centos-7                     READY
coreos-alpha-1122-0-0-v20160727      coreos-cloud     coreos-alpha                 READY
coreos-beta-1081-5-0-v20160718       coreos-cloud     coreos-beta                  READY
coreos-stable-1068-8-0-v20160718     coreos-cloud     coreos-stable                READY
debian-8-jessie-v20160718            debian-cloud     debian-8                     READY
opensuse-13-2-v20160222              opensuse-cloud                                READY
opensuse-leap-42-1-v20160302         opensuse-cloud                                READY
rhel-6-v20160718                     rhel-cloud       rhel-6                       READY
rhel-7-v20160718                     rhel-cloud       rhel-7                       READY
sles-11-sp4-v20160301                suse-cloud                                    READY
sles-12-sp1-v20160301                suse-cloud                                    READY
ubuntu-1204-precise-v20160627        ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1204-lts              READY
ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20160627         ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1404-lts              READY
ubuntu-1510-wily-v20160715           ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1510                  READY
ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20160721         ubuntu-os-cloud  ubuntu-1604-lts              READY
windows-server-2008-r2-dc-v20160719  windows-cloud    windows-2008-r2              READY
windows-server-2012-r2-dc-v20160719  windows-cloud    windows-2012-r2              READY
```

The "FAMILY" column is the one you're interested in.